# Why a struct in C seems to be allocated only in Flash(ROM) memory?

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I have written a simple test code and I found out accidentally that a lookup table in structure seems to be allocated in Flash memory and I don't know how to explain it. Here is the simple code :

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct PEC {
    uint8_t lookup[31] ;
};

uint8_t r;

int main() {

uint8_t r = rand() % 20;

    while(1) {

    struct PEC access = {
0x00U, 0x07U, 0x0EU, 0x09U, 0x1CU, 0x1BU, 0x12U, 0x15U,
0x38U, 0x3FU, 0x36U, 0x31U, 0x24U, 0x23U, 0x2AU, 0x2DU,
0x70U, 0x77U, 0x7EU, 0x79U, 0x6CU, 0x6BU, 0x62U, 0x65U,
0x48U, 0x4FU, 0x46U, 0x41U, 0x54U, 0x53U} ;

volatile uint8_t v = access.lookup[r] ;
_delay_ms(1500);
    }
}
```

and the compiler has the output :

### AVR Memory Usage

Device: atmega168

Program:     870 bytes (5.3% Full)
(.text + .data + .bootloader)

Data:          5 bytes (0.5% Full)
(.data + .bss + .noinit)

Could you explain me if the allocation is in Flash?
I think that during the execution the lookup table is not on that Stack, am I wrong?
Why a struct is not allocated on the Stack?

Comment: The lookup table *initialization values* are stored in flash. They are copied to the stack at run time to initialize the structure. So the structure *is* on the stack (you can confirm this by looking at the assembly code). Note that the memory usage report doesn't tell you anything about stack usage.

Comment: It's a lookup table.  You don't want it in flash?

Comment: Your struct gets initialized.  The initialization values must be stored in nonvolatile memory, which is flash.  Then the program never modifies the the struct contents.  So perhaps the compiler realizes that a RAM copy of the struct is not necessary and therefore it uses only the flash copy.

Comment: @Martin James I wont this in Flash but i am confused because i did not used an __attribute__ macro to tell the compiler where i want it!!

Comment: @kkrambo so are you sure that i am right and the compiler don't use the Stack ? i am not 100% sure that i understand the compilers output right!

Comment: I believe your `access` struct declared in `main()` _will_ be allocated on the stack.  You can probably tell by looking at the generated assembly code: the prologue for `main` will probably decrement `SP` by 32 bytes or so (31 for the struct and 1 for local variable `r` (which will prevent you from accessing the global variable of the same name!)  As @user3386109 and @kkrambo state, the data in Flash is initialization...it's copied to the local (stack) variable `access` somewhere at the beginning of `main`.

Comment: Several of these comments are in fact answers - this is not what SO comments are for. One of you post an answer! Or I will and take the credit.

Comment: As a side-note, how does that memory output make sense? Program: ... `.data`. Data: ... `.data`. It should say `.rodata` in the first case.

Comment: Please provide the Assembler code as generated by the compiler. Is somewhat doubt there is any access to the table (presuming this is a [mcve]. And how do you know it is **not** on the stack? For the static RAM foot print it cannot be deduced.

Answer (score 2):

The initializer list for the struct will always be in flash (.rodata or .text) no matter what you do.

The struct itself is local scope, so it would typically end up in RAM. However, the compiler probably noticed that you never modify the contents of the struct and therefore optimized it away entirely, grabbing the values directly from flash.

(Given that this is some 8 bit MCU which probably doesn't have flash wait states, this would be a viable optimization.)

To experiment, you could declare the struct variable `volatile` and see if you get increase use of RAM.

The best practice is however to declare the struct as `const`. If you need a modifiable copy of it in RAM, with all values initialized to defaults, you could do like this:

```
static const struct PEC table =  { ... };
...
struct PEC local = table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood that memory usage data. Your LUT is been allocated in
RAM, not in flash. But since it is allocated during *run time* (it's
stack allocation), it does not show in this *compile time* memory usage
analysis.

The fact that it is not allocated in flash does not mean it doesn't eat
flash space. In fact, it is being quite wasteful of flash. It would be
more efficient to allocate it in the “data” section of the program (i.e.
both in flash *and* in RAM), and yet more efficient to have it in flash
only. You can easily control the place where the LUT is allocated simply
by adding some qualifiers to the variable.

### Stack allocation

With the program as you wrote it (no qualifiers), the LUT is allocated
in RAM, on the stack, during the execution of `main()`. It is **not**
allocated in flash. Well, the contents must obviously be somewhere in
the flash, but it is not stored as an array. Instead, the data is
embedded in the instruction stream in the form of `ldi` (load immediate)
instructions. These instructions load a register with a constant value
contained in the instruction itself. Here is an excerpt of the
disassembly of `main()`:

```
ldi r24, 0x65  ; load register r24 with the constant 0x65
std Y+24, r24  ; store r24 in the stack
ldi r24, 0x48  ; load r24 with the constant 0x48
std Y+25, r24  ; store r24 in the stack
...etc...
```

Here, `Y` is used as a frame pointer, and `Y+24`, `Y+25`, ... are
frame-relative addresses pointing to the LUT in the stack.

It should be noted that, since the LUT is defined in block scope, this
whole initialization is repeated on each iteration of the loop. Also,
the compiler tries to optimize all this by keeping as much of the LUT as
possible in internal registers, in order to move most of these `ldi` out
of the loop. But since half of the CPU registers (r0 through r15) are
not ldi-capable, this requires extra “move” instructions:

```
before the loop:
    ...
    ldi r18, 0x07  ; load r18 with the constant 0x07
    mov r3, r18    ; copy r18 into r3
    ldi r19, 0x0E  ; load r19 with the constant 0x0E
    mov r4, r19    ; copy r19 into r4
    ...

inside the loop:
    ...
    std Y+2, r3  ; store r3 in the stack
    std Y+3, r4  ; store r4 in the stack
    ...
```

Each LUT entry optimized this way uses three instructions instead of
two, but only one of them is in the loop. All this ends up being quite
wasteful of flash, with two to three 2-byte instructions per LUT entry.
It also greatly slows down the loop iterations. If the LUT is moved to
function (instead of block) scope, the initialization is done only once,
we get rid of those `mov` instructions, and the loop is not slowed down
anymore. But things can be yet more efficient if we simply move the LUT
out of the stack.

### The data section

The LUT can be moved to the data section of the program by making it a
global variable or – perhaps more appropriately – by giving it
the `static` qualifier. In this case it is allocated in flash *as an
array*, which is way more efficient than having the same data embedded
in the instructions stream (1 byte instead of 4–6 bytes per entry). The
data section of the flash is copied to the data section of RAM at
program startup, before `main()` is called.

### In flash only

If the LUT is constant, having it copied to RAM is still somewhat
wasteful. The compiler can be instructed to keep that data in flash
– and access it from there when needed – by qualifying it as
`static __flash const`. The `__flash` qualifier is not standard C, but
it is supported by gcc as a “named address space”, a notion defined in
the [C extensions for embedded
systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_C).

This only works in C mode though. If compiling C++ code, one must resort
to the yet less standard and more primitive
[PROGMEM](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html)
attribute, which requires the subscript operator (`array[index]`) to be
replaced with a call to `pgm_read_byte()`.

The only drawback of having a constant LUT in flash rather than RAM is a
very slightly increased execution time: reading a byte from flash takes
3 CPU cycles, v.s. 2 cycles for reading RAM.

### Memory usage comparison

I did some tests compiling the program with gcc 4.9.2 and various
combinations of qualifiers. It should be noted that `const` does not
affect the generated code in the slightest way, but it is required if
`__flash` is used. `static` is also required for `__flash`, except on
global variables.

```
flash   RAM    qualifiers             scope
──────────────────────────────────────────────
 866      5    NONE, const            block
 826      5    NONE, const            function
 722     37    static, static const
 722      5    static __flash const
```

The RAM column here refers only to the RAM that is allocated at compile
time (data + bss): it does not include stack usage. If stack usage was
counted, only the last line of the table would show a small RAM
footprint.